# How can I convert Scanner Class into String?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cond { 
    static ScannerClass usrID, pwdd;
    static String pass = "123456";
    static String usr = "ABCD";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        System.out.println("Enter UserID: ");
        usrID = new ScannerClass();
        
        usrID.main();
        String o = usrID.toString();
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        pwdd = new ScannerClass();
        pwdd.main1();
        String t = pwdd.toString();

        
        if ((usr.equals(o)) && (pass.equals(t))) {
            System.out.println("You are logged in!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(("Please enter correct credentials"));
        }
    }
}
```

I made a seperate class which is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ScannerClass {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public  void main(){
        
        String UserID = sc.nextLine();
    }
    public void main1(){
        String pwd = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The code is not reunning as I expected . this is the problem:

---

Enter UserID:
ABCD
Enter password:
123456
Please enter correct credentials

---

I tried to convert the Scanner class using toString() I found this on internt but it is not working as you can see in the above results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `main` inside `ScannerClass` reads from the user, creates a local variable with its contents and discard the variable. The first change inside your method is to *return* the local variable so you can access it in other places:

```java
public class ScannerClass {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String getUserId(){
        String UserID = sc.nextLine();
        return UserID;
    }

    public void getPassword(){
        String pwd = sc.nextLine();
        return pwd;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Cond` main method, you can do

```java
ScannerClass scanner = new ScannerClass();
        
System.out.println("Enter UserID: ");
String usrID = scanner.getUserId();

System.out.println("Enter password: ");
String pwd = scanner.getPassword();

if ((usr.equals(usrID)) && (pass.equals(pwd))) {
    System.out.println("You are logged in!");
} else {
    System.out.println(("Please enter correct credentials"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ScannerClass has no constructor, so calling `new` on it doesn't do what you want (setting any variables in that class). Plus, you'll need to learn about variable scope in more detail.

Instead, you want getter methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerClass {
    private final Scanner sc; 

    public ScannerClass() {
        this.sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    } 
    
    public String getUserID(){
        return sc.nextLine();
    }

    public String getPwd(){
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Then, in your main method, you only need one scanner

```
ScannerClass sc = new ScannerClass();
String uid = sc.getUserID();
String pwd = sc.getPwd();
```

(Note: Both methods return the exact same thing, so creating a new object at all, only to rename `Scanner.nextLine`, is generally considered bad practice)

That's already a String. I don't know why you'd want to call toString on a String, but calling it on the ScannerClass object is incorrect (print the output, and you'll see why)

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the `Scanner` class correctly: your ScannerClass is more or less useless because all you are doing is using a `static Scanner` instance.

You would rather do that:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // 1
   System.out.println("Enter UserID: ");       
   String o = scanner.nextLine(); // (2)
   System.out.println("Enter password: ");
   String t = scanner.nextLine(); // (3)
   if (usr.equals(o) && pass.equals(t)) {
     System.out.println("You are logged in!");
   } else {
     System.out.println("Please enter correct credentials");
   }
 }
```

1. You should normally use try with resource here especially if you held the resource. This avoid handle leaks which in the specific case of `System.in`, this is less problematic and even rarer.
2. We use nextLine() to get the next line as user but this may fails if there is new next line: you should normally call `hasNextLine()` before: `nextLine()` *may* fails for example if stdin is no longer here (end of
   file, etc)
3. See 2.

Since you are reading password, you could also use `Console` with the benefits of hiding the password, but it may not work well in IDE such as Eclipse:

```
Console cons = System.console()
if (cons == null) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("no console");
}
String o = cons.readLine("Enter UserID: ");
char[] t = cons.readPassword("Enter Password: ");
if (usr.equals(o) && t != null && Arrays.equals(pass.toCharArray(), t)) {
  System.out.println("You are logged in!");
} else {
  System.out.println("Please enter correct credentials");
}
```

If you want to keep your ScannerClass, then you would be best having a static method getting all information from user:

```
class ScannerClass  {
  private final String userId;
  private final String password;
  private ScannerClass(String userId, String password) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.password = password;
  }
  
  public String getUserId() {return userId;}
  public String getPassword() {return password;}

  static ScannerClass  obtainFrom(/*WontClose*/ InputStream is) { // (1)
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
    System.out.println("Enter UserID: ");       
    String o = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    String t = scanner.nextLine();
    return new ScannerClass(o, t);
  }
}
```

Notice we don't close the `Scanner` (1) instance because Scanner.close will close the `InputStream`, which may or may not be wanted.

You can then use it:

```
ScannerClass scanner = ScannerClass.obtainFrom(System.in);
String o = scanner.getUserId();
String t = scanner.getPassword();
```

The benefit of doing that is to separate concerns: `obtainFrom` gets information and ScannerClass said information.

Comment: Downvoted, because this contains bad advice. You should *not* use try-with-resources for a Scanner created from System.in. Closing the Scanner closes the inner InputStream, which will lead to nasty surprises in the case of System.in.

Comment: As I said, this is less problematic with `System.in` but it still is: using System.in in Java is are and you will in most case use proper file based `InputStream`. Anyway, fixed the answer...